# SplideJS no arrow, no dots, no pause doesn't work

Tags: slider, splidejs

On this codepen it seems pause on hover can't be false, removing dots and arrows also not!
https://codepen.io/rafael-andrews/pen/Vwxvmgg

I tried below but nothing seems to work.

```
pauseOnHover: 'false',
drag        : 'false',
slideFocus  : 'false',
arrows      : 'false',
pagination  : 'false',
```

Comment: Without quotes it works. Only pauseOnHover: false, doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are passing boolean value (false) but in quote so it will work as a string not boolean

this is wrong

```
pauseOnHover: 'false',
drag        : 'false',
slideFocus  : 'false',
arrows      : 'false',
pagination  : 'false',
```

use this:

```
pauseOnHover: false,
drag        : false,
slideFocus  : false,
arrows      : false,
pagination  : false,
```

tried this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  new Splide('.splide', {
    type   : 'loop',
    drag   : 'free',
    focus  : 'center',
    pauseOnHover: false,
    drag        : false,
    slideFocus  : false,
    arrows      : false,
    pagination  : false,
    perPage: 3,
    autoScroll: {
      speed: 1,
    },
  }).mount( window.splide.Extensions );
});
```